# Is there any function formula in excel I can use to get a weighted geometric mean?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

The normal GEOMEAN function is assuming that all the various numbers are equally weighted, but in this case it's not, so how can I calculate a weighted geometric mean?

Answer (score 1):

There's no built-in formula for this, but you can use SUMPRODUCT to assist. See: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/214049

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `SUMPRODUCT` to calculate a **weighted average** but I'm not sure how you can do that with a weighted geometric mean.

Assuming values in `A1:D1` and weights in `A2:D2` try this "array formula"

`=PRODUCT(A1:D1^(A2:D2/SUM(A2:D2)))`

confirmed with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER so that curly braces like { and } appear around the formula

if all the values in A2:D2 (the weights) are the same then that formula will give you the same result as

`=GEOMEAN(A1:D1)`

That formula should give you the same results as the calculator [here](http://njinstruments.com/statistics/online-weighted-geometric-mean-calculator.html)

Note: you can remove the SUM function if weights sum to 1